# how to remove accents over a variable received in php

Tags: php, html, dojo

I want to remove the accents received from a :

```
Name : < input type="text" name = "nome" size="35" maxlength="50" required>
```

and also from a :

```
Outros :< br >< textarea name="outros" id="Outros" rows="5" cols="50" ></textarea></p>
```

because I can't receive the "values" with the accents and  I've tried many things, so I prefer remove it.

My main goal was to get the value of these fields and send them in a `powershell` script. 
It runs fine until you get to php. when PHP runs it shows the values ​​with accents, but when it sends email via `powershell`, and the disappear instead of appearing letters with accents accents appear question marks (?)

Name `input type="text";`

Date of departure `input type="text"` with a `Dojo calendar;`

Cancel Phone Number: Yes / No `input type="radio";`

Cancel the data plate: Yes / No `input type="radio";`

Other: `textarea`.

Comment: i tried to use <meta http-equiv="content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" /> to put accents but when i send the email they disappear.

Comment: HTML email doesn't support meta tags. You should put it in the `Content-type:` header of the email.

Comment: not even the outlook 2013 ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, in .Net I solve this converting the string to ASCII and then back to UTF.

Comment: but the real problem is i send the email with  charset=iso-8859-2 just ~ and ^ is converted the other accents no